# Conditional probability between two random vectors: input and output of a channel.

Tags: probability, definition, information-theory

Suppose we send a sequence of $n$ bits $X=\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ through a channel. Each $x_k=1$ with probability $p$, and $x_k=0$ w.p. $1-p$. The channel flips one input bit with probability $q$. If $Y=\{y_1,...,y_n\}$ is the output of the channel, then

> How would you define the conditional probability
>   $P(Y|X)=P(y_1,...,y_n|x_1,...,x_n)$ in terms of $p$ and $q$?

I'm pretty sure there is a simple form but I can't see it.

Comment: Is each of the $y_k$ dependending only in $x_k$ or in all $(x_1,...,x_n)$?

Comment: If the answer to @sinbadh 's question is yes and your x_i are independent, you only need to compute $P (Y_i = y_i | X_i =x_i) = q1_{x_i =0} + (1-q)1_{x_i =1}$

Comment: @sinbadh Yes, each $y_k$ depends only in its corresponding $x_k$.

Comment: @Cornelis And how can I write $P(Y|X)$ in terms of $P(y_i|x_i)$?

Comment: By $P(Y = (y_1, \ldots , y_n) ) = \Pi_1^n P(Y_i = y_i),$ assuming the $Y'$s are independent. Similarly you would get $P(Y|X) = \Pi_1^n P(Y_i = y_i | X_i = x_i)$